# Setenv in c programming usage?

Tags: c, setenv

```
#include <stdio h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[])
{
    int i = 0;
    while (envp[i] != NULL)
    {
        if (strstr(envp[i], "SHLVL") != NULL)
            printf("%s\n", envp[i]);
        i++;
    }
  
    setenv("SHLVL", "stackoverflow", 2);
    i = 0;
    while (envp[i] != NULL)
    {
        if (strstr(envp[i], "SHLVL") != NULL)
            printf("%s\n", envp[i]);
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In this code `SHLVL` is an existing environmental variable. When I try to change the value of that variable using `setenv` it gives expected output.

```
SHLVL=1
SHLVL=stackoverflow
```

In another case:
The same code with non-existent environmental variable

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[])
{
    int i = 0;
    while (envp[i] != NULL)
    {
        if (strstr(envp[i], "SHLVL") != NULL)
            printf("%s\n", envp[i]);
        i++;
    }

    setenv("arr", "33", 2); // non-exist environmental variable 
    setenv("SHLVL", "stackoverflow", 2);
    i = 0;
    while (envp[i] != NULL)
    {
        if (strstr(envp[i], "SHLVL") != NULL)
            printf("%s\n", envp[i]);
        i++;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here the `arr` is an non-exist environmental variable. This code give output as

```
SHLVL=1
SHLVL=1
```

My question is how the non-existing environmental variable change the output here? Here I am using gcc compiler.

Comment: When you add a new environment variable, the environment array has to be reallocated. So `envp` doesn't point to it any more.

Comment: Use `getenv()` to read environment variables rather than searching `envp`.

Comment: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/setenv.html <- "envp may point to an obsolete copy of the environment"

Comment: If you want a variable to play with, try [`extern char **environ`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/environ.7.html) instead.

Comment: Just suspecting, but the entire matter might get even worse if you *delete* a variable (after adding a new one) – if `envp` doesn't point to the actual environment any more it most likely won't get updated either then and the pointer for the deleted environment variable is dangling, using it would result in UB.

Comment: @Barmar `getenv()` requires you to know exactly which environment variable you want to read. There's no way in standard C to get a list of all environment variables (`extern char **environ` is non-standard).

Comment: @KeithThompson The OP seems to be looking for the specific variable `SHLVL`, although they're misusing `strstr()`, which will find any variable that to contain `SHLVL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `envp` argument in `main` points to the original array with environment variable definitions. When you set en environment variable using `setenv()`:

- If the variable already exists, the array is not reallocated, only the entry for the variable is changed, hence enumerating the array pointed to by `envp` gives the expected output.
- If the variable does not exist, the array with all definitions needs to be extended and may need to be reallocated or moved for this purpose, hence the `envp` pointer that still points to the original array does not have the current definition strings that are present in the new array, the one used by `getenv()` to locate the current definitions. In this case, enumerating the values using `envp` will not find the new variable definition and if an existing variable is changed afterwards as in your example, only the new array is modified, the original array pointed to by `envp` is not modified so it still has the original definition.  This explains what you observe, but this behavior is not guaranteed as, depending on the implementation, the original array might have enough space at the end for the new definition and thus would not need to be reallocated for each new variable.

This behavior is very tricky and has far reaching consequences for the memory management of definition strings.  Passing the `envp` to `main` is not standard and only available on unix systems, but even on these systems, a preferred way of enumerating the environment definitions is to use the global variable [`environ`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/environ.7.html) that is updated by `setenv()` and `putenv()`:

```
extern char **environ;
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, you should use `getenv`, for example

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[])
{
    printf("%s\n", getenv("SHLVL")); // Print the current value of SHLVL

    setenv("SHLVL", "stackoverflow", 1); // Change SHLVL to "stackoverflow"
    
    printf("%s\n", getenv("SHLVL")); // Print the new value of SHLVL

    return 0;
}
```

The `envp` parameter in the `main` function contains a snapshot of the env vars available to the program **at the start** and changes to the environment using `setenv` or `unsetenv` do not affect this array directly. Instead, they change the actual process environment.